# Paginated UIWebview ignore CSS background property since iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Since iOS 10.3, if paginationMode attribute of an UIWebView is set to UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight, the CSS property background of the html loaded page is ignore.

This is a bug on Apple side, so I filled a bug report : [radar/31552458](http://openradar.appspot.com/31552458)

However, I really need to fix this bug in my application, or find a workaround. 
Setting the UIWebView background to clear and opaque to NO is not working on paginated webviews.

### EDIT 06/21/2017 : Durty workaround

As I found no clean solution to fix my issue, I embedded my HTML body content inside a div and apply the background color to this div. However, sometime the div doesn't fill the last page, so the background doesn't cover my last page.

Embed my html content in a main div in code using [HTMLReader](https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader) lib :

```
- (NSString *)encapsulateHTMLFromData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding];

    HTMLDocument *document = [HTMLDocument documentWithString:html];

    NSOrderedSet *children = [document.bodyElement children];

    HTMLElement *div = [[HTMLElement alloc] initWithTagName:@"div" attributes:@{@"id":@"my_main_container"}];

    for (HTMLNode *child in children)
    {
        [div addChild:child];
    }

    [document.bodyElement addChild:div];

    return [document innerHTML];
}
```

Change background color on main div :

```
NSString *kCSSBody = @"body{margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important} #my_main_container{-webkit-hyphens:auto; text-align:justify; padding:1em 1em 1em 1em; background-color:#123456;}";

- (void)changeBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backColor
{
    NSString *hexBackColor = [self hexStringFromColor:backColor];
    NSString *css = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@{ background-color:%@;}", @"#my_main_container", hexBackColor];
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('my_css').innerHTML='%@'", css];

    [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

Comment: Hi @vmeyer  Did you fix this issue?

Comment: No, the bug is still running on iOS 10.3+ versions. 
I had to embed my html content inside a custom div and set the background to this div. I can post my workaround if you need it, but it's not satisfying to me.

Comment: Can you please post what you have @vmeyer? I have also similar kind of issue. And I wrapped the content into a div but the background is not covering the full view. If I write position: relative or fixed in CSS, then the pagination stopped working.

Comment: @Simant I edited my question with my quick workaround. This does'nt really resolve the issue as my background is neither covering the full view. 
Moreover, as webview pagination is working with CSS column propertie, you could try to implement your own column system. (See this documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_7_0.html)